# Creating an array from vectors on matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have 3 vectors x,y and z. How can I create an array a so that a(i,j,k) = [x(i),y(j),z(k)]?

I tried

```
a(:,:,1) = [[1,2];[3,4]]
```

but got

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

*edit after comment*

Basically I first wanted to create an array a from x,y,z, but here is my original problem (so I think creating a vector would be better):
I have three vectors: x,y,z, say x = [1 2 3], y = [4,3,2] z = [1,3,2]

I want to compute the gaussian probability function on each [x_i,y_j,z_k]
I was thinking using an array. So I first tried using mvnpdf with an array a:

```
a = rand(3,3,3) < 0.1
```

and `mvnpdf(a,[1,2,3],eye(3))`

But matlab returned the following error:

```
Error using mvnpdf (line 46)
X must be a matrix.
```

Apparently, he is not happy with me using arrays.

Do you have any idea how I could compute what I want to (apart from using for loops that would take far too long for the size of my real vectors x,y,z).

Comment: You want a(i,j,k) to be a _vector_?

Comment: Doesn't `a = [x(:) y(:) z(:)]` do what you want? Seems `mvnpdf(a,...)` needs the first input argument `a` to be `N-by-D`.

Comment: @chappjc not really because I want to compute the mvnpdf for all the combinations x(i),y(j),z(k) (I think your solution would give me only the mvnpdf for x(i),y(i),z(i) right?

Comment: Yes, I see now. Luis' answer looks good for all combinations.

Comment: @teaLeef - It would be helpful if you explicitly stated the order in which you would like x,y,z to vary in the output `N-by-D` matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
x = [10 20 30 40 50]; % example x
y = [100 200 300 400]; % example y
z = [1000 2000 3000]; % example z.    

[ii jj kk] = ndgrid(1:length(x), 1:length(y), 1:length(z));
a = cat(4, x(ii), y(jj), z(kk));
```

The resulting `a` is a 4-D array of size `length(x)`x`length(y)`x`length(z)`x`3`. The fourth dimension refers to the three elements of the desired vector. So your desired result `[x(i),y(j),z(k)]` would be given by `a(i,j,k,:)`, or rather `squeeze(a(i,j,k,:)).'`. For example,

```
>> squeeze(a(1,2,3,:)).'
ans =
          10         200        3000
```

---

Following your comments, and with thanks to @chappjc: If you want all those vectors piled up as rows of a three-column matrix in lexicographical order, just use:

```
[kk jj ii] = ndgrid(1:length(z), 1:length(y), 1:length(x));
b = [x(ii(:)).' y(jj(:)).' z(kk(:)).'];
```

Result:

```
>> b(1,:)
ans =
          10         100        1000

>> b(2,:)
ans =
          10         100        2000
```

etc.

Comment: a(1,2,3,:) is still a 4-D array. Is there anyway to get a vector instead? (because of the error I get from mvnpdf when I use an array)? Thanks

Comment: Yes, see my answer. `squeeze(a(1,2,3,:))` is a column vector, and `squeeze(a(1,2,3,:)).'` is a row vector.

Comment: would the order be different? (it's important in my case)

Comment: @teaLeef Note that using `meshgrid` instead of `ndgrid` would give wrong results. For instance, with my example data `squeeze(a(2,4,3,:))` would give 40, 200, 3000, which is wrong. So `ndgrid` is the way to go.

Comment: @LuisMendo I have one more question in fact: I would like to create the matrix [x(i),y(j),z(k)]. I know I can do this with a for loop and squeeze as well, but it's taking too long to run. So I tried squeeze(a) but the result is still a 4-D array. Do you know a better way to do that than with loops?

Comment: @teaLeef I don't see how you can define that to be a matrix. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @LuisMendo Basically I want to create a very big matrix (1,000,000 rows) that would contain [x(1),y(1),z(1)], [x(1),y(1),z(2)], [x(1),y(2),z(1)] etc (all the combinations)

Comment: @teaLeef I see now. Try `b = [x(ii(:)) y(jj(:)) z(kk(:))];`. Check the resulting order

Comment: @teaLeef That `b` gives the following order: [x(1) y(1) z(1)], then [x(2) y(1) z(1)] etc (the first variable varies more quickly, then the second, then the third). Anyway, it gives all combinations

Comment: `b = [x(ii(:)); y(jj(:));z(kk(:))]';` is what I want. Thanks a bunch again!

Comment: @teaLeef - If you decide you need it a different way, you can always change the order by reordering the inputs/outputs of `ndgrid`, keeping in mind that the first in/out pair changes fastest, then the second, etc.  This is why `ndgrid` is more intuitive than `meshgrid` IMO.  That's all from me, promise!

Comment: @chappjc  I don't see what you mean by "keeping in mind that the first in/out pair changes fastest, then the second, etc" Could you give me a small eg please?

Comment: @teeLeef My answer now includes chappjc's suggestions, and gives the vectors in your intended order